# Office 365 API timeout when using Invoke-RestMethod or System.Net.WebClient

Tags: powershell, office365

I am creating a PowerShell script for downloading all emails with attachments from a mailbox, and deleting them from the mailbox after successful download.

I currently use the https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/me/messages endpoint. Opening a browser and logging on is always successful and quick (less than 1 second response).

However, trying to run the following PowerShell returns timeout for the Invoke-RestMethod and the WebClient.

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/me/messages"
Invoke-RestMethod $url -Credential $cred -Method GET -TimeoutSec 100

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = $cred
$wc.DownloadString("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/me/messages")
```

I have tried this in a few test tenants, and some production tenants with the same error. I have also tried the https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages, with even less success (does not work in browser, and not with PowerShell).

Also, it is not only the messages-endpoint that has this error, I have also tried https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Calendar/ with same result.

1. I have no proxy servers
2. I have tried from my customers network, my office network, home network
3. Some times it works just fine, other times not at all

Anyone had any success with this API?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be hitting a known issue. If you increase your timeout value does it eventually return? If so, and you repeat the request, does it return more quickly?

As a side note, invoking the endpoint with this cmdlet uses Basic authentication, which is currently enabled on the REST endpoints, but will be disabled sometime in the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. Actually, it times out no matter how big the timeout is. One fun thing I have found is that when it is working (as I write, some times it works), one way to make it STOP working is to invoke a "Delete" on an email like this:

Invoke-RestMethod $query -Credential $cred -Method Delete

- This actually breaks everything for some reason, now sending a get command will no longer work.

On the basic auth note - are there any way of doing it "the right way" with Invoke-RestMethod?

Comment: The REST APIs require a Bearer token retrieved from the OAuth2 endpoints of Azure Active Directory. I don't think that cmdlet supports the OAuth2 flows.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to skip using this API and instead use the EWS Managed API. Here is a code example for those who are interested:

```
# Destination folder
$destinationFolder = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Attachment Downloader"

# replace with your email address
$email    = "email@office365tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$username = "email@office365tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password123"

# load the assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

# Create Exchange Service object
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1)
$s.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
# $s.TraceEnabled = $true
Write-Host "Trying AutoDiscover... "
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($email, {$true})

if(!$s.Url) {
    Write-Error "AutoDiscover failed"
    return;
} else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "AutoDiscover succeeded - $($s.Url)"
}

# Create destination folder
$destinationFolder = "{0}\{1}" -f $destinationFolder, (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd HHmmss")
mkdir $destinationFolder | Out-Null

# get a handle to the inbox
$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

#create a property set (to let us access the body & other details not available from the FindItems call)
$psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;

# Find the items
Write-Host "Searching for items in mailbox... " -NoNewline
$items = $inbox.FindItems(500)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "found $($items.items.Count)"

$inc = 0;
foreach ($item in $items.Items)
{
    # Create mail folder
    $inc += 1
    $mailFolder = "{0}\{1}" -f $destinationFolder, $inc; 
    mkdir $mailFolder | Out-Null

    # load the property set to allow us to get to the body
    $item.load($psPropertySet)
    Write-Host ("$inc - $($item.Subject)") -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # save the metadata to a file
    $item | Export-Clixml ("{0}\metadata.xml" -f $mailFolder)

    # save all attachments
    foreach($attachment in $item.Attachments) {
        if($attachment.ContentType -notlike "message/*") {
            Write-Host " - $($attachment.Name) ($($attachment.ContentType))"
            $fileName = "{0}\{1}" -f $mailFolder, $attachment.Name
            $attachment.Load($fileName)
        }
    }

    # delete the mail item
    $item.Delete([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::HardDelete, $true)
}
```